# Unable to move file to another folder with UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have set up the permissions to access a Document folder.

I am able to access the file in a folder stored in Documents.

I could not understand why the below code is not working.

```
public static async void CopyTheFile(StorageFolder _subfolder, string strfilenm)  
{
    try
    {
        string strPathTarget = @"C:\Users\xxx-user\Documents\MyTravel"; 

        StorageFolder Bufolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(strPathTarget);

         var targetFile = await _subfdl.GetFileAsync(strfilenm);             

         await targetFile.CopyAsync(Bufolder, strfilenm, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

         await targetFile.DeleteAsync(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }   

}
```

this folder I  have manually created and now I need to access it and move old files to here.

```
string strPathTarget = @"C:\Users\xxx-user\Documents\MyTravel";
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Exception? If so, what is it?

Comment: Can not use void as this method is async:  await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(strPathTarget). Thus, not error catch at all.

Comment: [Never ever use async void](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary` instead of `string strPathTarget = @"C:\Users\xxx-user\Documents\MyTravel`;

Like this:

```
public static async void CopyTheFile(StorageFolder _subfolder, string strfilenm) {
            try {
                StorageFolder Bufolder = await  KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFolderAsync("MyTravel") ;
                var targetFile = await _subfolder.GetFileAsync(strfilenm);
                await targetFile.CopyAsync(Bufolder, strfilenm, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                await targetFile.DeleteAsync();

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

        }
```

Don't forget that you need file assosiations when you access files within the directory. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint to the closing } of the catch line and tell what the exception is?

Comment: I tried, it wont stop there, it skip! I am reading files as they come in a loop. When a file found ,I use the above method move it to other folder.

Comment: then there is no exception there... it would make sense to put the breakpoint to the first line and going from there in that case. If that does not get activated then either the code is not executed or your setup is just defected.

Comment: Something wrong here:  StorageFolder Bufolder = await  KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFolderAsync("MyTravel")  When breakpoint hit here, it skip try-statement and go into loop. This method is executed but unable to catch the error. Something wrong wtih Knowfolder method

Comment: I think that is, because it is an async method and an exception is thrown.. anyway.. In order to KnownFolders to work you need two things in the Package.appxmanifest file: create a capability for the documentsLibrary (like this:     <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" /> ) and create at least 1 file fileTypeAssociation (this one you can do on the UI under declaration.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123450/discussion-between-gregkalapos-and-milkbottle).